# MySQL Trigger including table joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a trigger in MySQL for phpmyadmin that will insert data into two separate tables (IssueTable and JobTable) from a table called RefTable. I have the trigger working for my Issue table after returning a positive boolean value from within the RefTable, and data is being inserted. The JobTable insert is proving difficult.

Before inserting into JobTable from RefTable I need to check the value of a boolean within another table called ProjectTable; if this returns positive I then want to insert the data into JobTable.

Once I have both queries also need to join both of these queries as phpmyadmin will not work with multiple triggers.

My query for inserting data into the IssueTable is below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER To_Issue_Table
AFTER INSERT ON _RefTable

BEGIN

Declare EntryDate DATETIME;
SET EntryDate = CURDATE();

CASE WHEN (new.ServiceCall) = 1
THEN INSERT INTO `_IssueTable`( `RefID`, `IssueEntryDate`, `IssueDesc`, `ResponseID`)
VALUES
( new.RefID, EntryDate, new.ProjectScope, new.ResponseID);
END CASE;

END
```

RESOLVED as below - One field of data is not copying across but not a big deal yet.
I have ammended the query and it is submitting and the IssueTable is being populated, however the JobTable is not:

```
BEGIN

Declare EntryDate DATETIME;
Declare SurveyReqVar INT;
Declare CurrentProjectID INT;
SET EntryDate = CURDATE();
SET CurrentProjectID = new.ProjectID;
SET SurveyReqVar = 
(SELECT `SurveyReq`
        FROM _ProjectTable
        WHERE ProjectID = CurrentProjectID);

CASE WHEN (new.ServiceCall) = 1
THEN INSERT INTO `_IssueTable`( `RefID`, `IssueEntryDate`, `IssueDesc`, `ResponseID`)
VALUES
( new.RefID, EntryDate, new.ProjectScope, new.ResponseID);

WHEN (SurveyReqVar) = 1
THEN INSERT INTO `_JobTable`( `RefID`, `JobDetails`, `JobEntryDate`)
VALUES
( new.RefID, new.ProjectScope, EntryDate);



END CASE;

END
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You have a single variable assigned to the result of a query that returns at least two columns and perhaps many rows.  Your trigger definition statement is incorrect.  And, you don't really describe the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited mistakes that were in the post. Does that help? I know my logic is off on how I set the variable as the select query to join tables and then call it. But I'm stuck on how to proceed to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved as below, one field of data is not copying but the rest are OK.

```
BEGIN

Declare EntryDate DATETIME;
Declare SurveyReqVar INT;
Declare CurrentProjectID INT;
SET EntryDate = CURDATE();
SET CurrentProjectID = new.ProjectID;
SET SurveyReqVar = 
(SELECT `SurveyReq`
        FROM _ProjectTable
        WHERE ProjectID = CurrentProjectID);

CASE WHEN (new.ServiceCall) = 1
THEN INSERT INTO `_IssueTable`( `RefID`, `IssueEntryDate`, `IssueDesc`, `ResponseID`)
VALUES
( new.RefID, EntryDate, new.ProjectScope, new.ResponseID);

WHEN (SurveyReqVar) = 1
THEN INSERT INTO `_JobTable`( `RefID`, `JobDetails`, `JobEntryDate`)
VALUES
( new.RefID, new.ProjectScope, EntryDate);



END CASE;

END
```